# Where can I find the type of Cognito's IAuthenticationCallback.onFailure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js

We're using [amazon-cognito-identity-js](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/main/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js) to authenticate a user via username and password, calling `cognitoUser.authenticateUser` and providing it with an `onFailure` callback.

We upgraded from 1.31.0 to 5.2.9 and it looks like the shape of the error object returned by `IAuthenticationCallback.onFailure` changed.

The old `err` looked like this

```js
{
  "@timestamp": "2022-07-11T10:41:50.924Z",
  "level": "ERROR",
  "message": {
    "code": "UserNotFoundException",
    "message": "User does not exist.",
    "requestId": "346602ab-aaaa-aaaa-babd-a7c252232604",
    "retryDelay": 74.33847546147882,
    "retryable": false,
    "statusCode": 400,
    "time": "2022-07-11T10:41:50.922Z"
  }
}
```

The new `err` looks like this

```js
{
  "@timestamp": "2022-07-11T10:39:27.963Z",
  "level": "ERROR",
  "message": {
    "code": "UserNotFoundException",
    "name": "UserNotFoundException"
  }
}
```

Our code was relying on the old `statusCode` field and hence broke. I'd like to future-proof this from further changes, but I can't find any documentation about what actually should be in that field.

None of the "use cases" do anything other than log/rethrow the error and the Typescript type is just `any` https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/main/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js/index.d.ts#L22

What is in `err` ?

Comment: Good question, I can also not find an enum that defines the available options for message.code or message.name. I am using typescript, and find it suprising that this is not better documented, as AWS are normally good at this stuff. I can't even find basic API documentation of the cognitoUser.authenticateUser() - all I can find from AWS is the "use cases" you also mention.